Need to integrate s3 with DBT pipeline
I am building a DBT data transformation pipeline which needs to read parquet data from s3 location and write the output again to another S3 location.
What are the configuration changes which will be needed in -

profiles.yml
How do I read the parquet in models sql file and store the output in s3 again.

*note: dont want to install duckdb or any other integration.
Expecting a seemless integration which pulls data from S3, processes it and stores the processed output back to another S3 location.

What is your desired format of the output files? Parquet?

Yes, it is parquet file format

Reading from Amazon S3 is easy. You can use read_files table-valued function | Databricks on AWS:
select * from read_files('s3://bucket_name/folder/', format => 'parquet')

You'll need to setup the S3 bucket as an External location | Databricks on AWS so that it has credentials to access the bucket.
Writing is more difficult. I actually run a Databricks Notebook after dbt has finished and use Python to extract data and write output Parquet files:
for table_name in tables_to_copy:
    
    df = spark.read.table(f"{input_database}.{input_schema}.{table_name}")
    df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(f's3://{output_bucket}/{run_timestamp}/{table_name}/')

An alternative might be to define a dbt model with Databricks configuration options to set the OUTPUT and LOCATION. However, I don't know what would happen on subsequent runs when there might be previous files in that location left from the prior runs.
